# Settings to block file:// urls to request resources from https:// urls in browsers

Tags: http, security, web, browser, https

I am building an app which wraps some content in html.  The users will be able to download this html file and view the content (which changes dynamically based on time and a few details fetched from our servers.

I would like to know if there is any settings on browsers that can block https:// requests from file:// urls?

It works by default, I am just concerned if there is any way users can do this. (browser settings, security zones or something like that)

I believe there is no code samples required for this.

Comment: I can't follow the 2nd paragraph from the 1st paragraph. Why do you need to block HTTPS requests? Do your users suppose to download the HTML files?

Comment: My guess is that the Asker doesn't need to, but is concerned about some setting that would prevent his app from working correctly, so he's asking pre-emptively.

Comment: @Benjamin. Thats right.  I am concerned if there is a way users can prevent file:/// urls to request resources from https:// urls

Answer (score 0):

There are windows group policy settings that can block browser downloads, but I'm not aware of browser specific settings. Here are a few links:

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/03/group-policy-setting-of-the-week-18-allow-file-downlaod-internet-explorer/

https://serverfault.com/questions/362974/how-can-i-disable-download-from-all-browsers-using-group-policy-for-domain-users

https://superuser.com/questions/578276/can-i-block-all-file-downloads-in-chrome